# Permission denied for git dependencies in package.json

Tags: node.js

I try setup git dependencies in package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "myLib": "git+ssh://git@domain.com:user/myLib.git"
  }
```

When I do `sudo npm install` I got errors:

```
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address 'myIp' to the list of known hosts.

 Permission denied (publickey).
```

Allthough I can clone successfully the same lib to that machine:

```
git clone git@domain.com:user/myLib.git
```

So I have valid ssh keys.

My OS is **OSX** but I have the same problem on **Linux**.

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: my operatin system is OsX

Comment: Does this work `git clone ssh://git@domain.com:user/myLib.git` ?

Comment: `git clone ssh://git@domain.com:user/myLib.git` don't work niether in console (`ssh: Could not resolve hostname domain.com:user: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.`
) nor in package.json nor on linux.

Comment: Looks like your git repo at `domain.com` does not accept ssh connections. You have to configure it to accept, or use `git://git@domain.com:user/myLib.git` instead of git+ssh in your package.json

Comment: `git://git@domain.com:user/myLib.git` failed in package.json: `fatal: Unable to look up git@bitbucket.org (port userName) (nodename nor servname provided, or not known)` ... and I doubt that my repo server dont accept ssh connections, because `"myLib": "git+ssh://git@domain.com:user/myLib.git"` is working when I do `npm install` on linux. So the problem is for mac only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I should run `npm install` without `sudo`.

If can not, then change permissions for node.js apps folder:

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` ~/pathToAll/node/apps.
```

So git ssh dependencies work well in package.json

Comment: While this solution may work, it contradicts advice in the NPM docs: "Use sudo for greater safety. Or don't, if you prefer not to." from https://github.com/npm/npm

Comment: Thanks! It seems backward, but this worked for me after failing to install using sudo.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved one scenario of this issue on Windows 10.

The problem was that I configured my git bash ~ (home) folder to **c:\home** and expected git to find **c:\home.ssh** folder while when git is running from **npm** even if starting from git bash, git used **C:\Users\.ssh**

The solution was to copy my .ssh folder (containing my ssh keys) to C:\Users\

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that allows for continued use of `sudo npm install`.

Add the following to a text file `/root/.ssh/config`:

```
Host domain.com
    User git 
    Port 22
    Hostname domain.com
    IdentityFile "/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa"
    TCPKeepAlive yes 
    IdentitiesOnly yes 
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

This configuration references the original key file even while using the `sudo` command for things like `sudo npm install`.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using 
    `sudo npm install`
instead use
    `npm install`

*Whenever using github repositories as a dependencies for your project.